# Debian Squeeze does not add OTF Fonts

Tags: debian, fonts

I am trying to add a few OTF fonts to my debian system. I copied the font folder in question over to /usr/share (`cp -R /home/morris/Desktop/Collected\ Fonts /usr/share/fonts`) and ran `fc-cache -f -v` which gave the following output:

```
/usr/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 4 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 30 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/Adobe Caslon Pro: caching, new cache contents: 6 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/Adobe Garamond Pro: caching, new cache contents: 6 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/Adobe Jenson Pro: caching, new cache contents: 32 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/Andale Mono: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/Bell Centennial Std: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/Caecilia LT Std: caching, new cache contents: 8 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/DIN 1451 Std: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/DIN 30640 Std: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/Didot LT Std: caching, new cache contents: 5 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/Egyptienne F LT Std: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/Folio Std: caching, new cache contents: 5 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/Frutiger LT Std: caching, new cache contents: 14 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/Futura Std: caching, new cache contents: 20 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/Helvetica Neue LT Std: caching, new cache contents: 51 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/ITC Cushing Std: caching, new cache contents: 8 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/ITC Officina Sans Std: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/ITC Officina Serif Std: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/Letter Gothic Std: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/LinoLetter Std: caching, new cache contents: 8 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/Memphis LT Std: caching, new cache contents: 7 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/Minion Pro: caching, new cache contents: 64 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/Museo: caching, new cache contents: 5 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/Myriad Pro: caching, new cache contents: 40 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/OCR A Std: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/OCR B Std: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/Olympian LT Std: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/Serifa Std: caching, new cache contents: 6 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/Syntax LT Std: caching, new cache contents: 5 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/Times New Roman MT Std: caching, new cache contents: 7 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Collected Fonts/Trade Gothic LT Std: caching, new cache contents: 14 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 6 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1: caching, new cache contents: 9 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/large: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/util: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 7 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont: caching, new cache contents: 12 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/openoffice: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu: caching, new cache contents: 21 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-liberation: caching, new cache contents: 12 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-lyx: caching, new cache contents: 9 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-sil-gentium: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-sil-gentium-basic: caching, new cache contents: 8 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/type1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 2 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts: caching, new cache contents: 35 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/type1/mathml: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts: skipping, no such directory
/usr/local/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/root/.fonts: skipping, no such directory
/var/cache/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
/root/.fontconfig: not cleaning non-existent cache directory
fc-cache: succeeded
```

I rebooted the system afterwards. However none of the new fonts show up neither in Prefernces > Appearance > Fonts or in OpenOffice Writer. Any ideas how to get this to work?

Comment: I have no idea if this is your problem (and it doesn't appear to be), but avoid spaces in filenames and directory names other than for your personal stuff. They can trip up unsuspecting utilities in weird and wonderful ways.

Comment: @Mat it most likely was my problem. i have removed the spaces and the fonts are showing up now. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Mat said, remove the spaces from your filenames. :)